# Cleaning data before fitting the Heston SVM

Tags: data, heston

This is more of a generic question regarding data cleaning. I have implemented the Heston SVM, and I am attempting to fit it to some historical option data. With simple cleaning of the implied volatility data, the error of the Heston model is quite large (20-30%). Is there any standard procedure for cleaning the data before fitting the model?

I have attempted several combinations of interpolation, polynomial fits, moving averages, Kernel smoothing, Savitzky-Golay filter...

Any suggestions?

Comment: One suggestion: you usually clean static arbitrages from the option data before fitting the model. I have made an [old answer here](https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/61035/51407) that links to a paper worth reading on how to exclude static arbitrages. Maybe that'll help to reduce the error?

Comment: It's generally difficult to fit SV models to market data. They aren't built to price vanilla options and if your main goal is to fit vanilla options LV would be better.

Comment: I see, appreciate the pointer. I did some more reading, and a local volatility model does not seem to be that accurate for the volatility surface. In Derman's Volatility Smile book, and when I took his class, he mentioned that the future skew in LV model is too flat, especially for equity index options. I'll probably look into stochastic local volatility models instead, like th Heston LVM.